# PHP Redirect w/ Arrays (Not working?)

Tags: php, arrays

I made a redirect script as listed below... no matter what value of p is passed, even if valid, it is redirected to the default.htm page... essentially it is skipping the if/else part and always going to the else.

Is there something special about the php header function where it is disregarding the conditional statements?

```
<?php

/*
Use the following link format:
<a href="goto.php?p=XXXXXX">XXXXXX</a>
*/

$p = $_GET['p'];
$link = array(

/*Links*/
'link1'=>'/link1.htm',
'link2'=>'/link2.htm',

);

/*Send Headers*/

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noarchive', true);

if (in_array($p, $link))
{
    header('Location: '.$link[$p]); // Valid p
}  
else
{
    header('Location: /default.htm'); // Invalid p
}

exit();
?>
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting comment it out and var_dump(in_array($p,$link)) and see if you're getting true or false.  If false, you know there's something going on with your $_GET['p'] and/or $link definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use array_key_exists some what like this

```
if ((array_key_exists('p', $_GET) && isset($link[$p]))
{
    header('Location: '.$link[$p]); // Valid p
}  
else
{
    header('Location: /default.htm'); // Invalid p
}
```

The above worked for me and also it wont show index undefined warning since you use array_key exists

Comment: I had to change to if (array_key_exists('p', $_GET) && isset($link[$p])) - removed an extra (, but this worked perfectly fine... thank you soo much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
if (in_array($p, $link))
```

you want:

```
if (array_key_exists($p, $link))
```

The first checks against the values (right of the `=>`s).  The second checks against the keys (left of the `=>`s).

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

The short version in your case is:

```
$link = @$link[$p] ?: '/default.htm';
header("Location: $link");
```

Which spares you the `if` and `else`.

Comment: Tried this and the result was a redirect to /$link no matter what value of p is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the value of `$_GET['p']` is in the values-list of `$link`, but then you're using it as the key in the `header()` call. It looks like you mean to if `$_GET['p']` is *a key* in the `$link` array.

To do this, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) instead of `in_array()` to check the array's keys (`in_array()` will check the array's values):

```
if (isset($link[$p])) {
    header('Location: '.$link[$p]); // Valid p
}
```

Comment: [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) is probably better then `isset` here

Comment: @Nile Personally, I think `array_key_exists()` is just a convenience-method for `isset()`. Also, per benchmark testing, `isset()` is a lot faster. I haven't confirmed, but I believe that they perform the same low-end tests to check for being set.

Comment: according to [this](http://www.zomeoff.com/php-fast-way-to-determine-a-key-elements-existance-in-an-array/), you should use both in case of that weird `null` case

Comment: @Nile The *weird `null` case* is what's experienced by inexperienced programmers; the documentation for `isset()` specifically says it returns false on `null` - that's why we use it. Also, it's perfectly applicable to the OP's question (so is using `array_key_exists()`; they both will perform the same task in this case)